# Lumia Camera Tap to Take Photo

Tags: lumia, camera

In the `Lumia Camera` app, how do I tap the screen once to take a photo? (Without having to hit the Camera/Take photo icon).

In the default Windows Phone Camera App there is a setting called `Tap to take photo` in the Camera settings.

(I have a Nokia 640).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not seem to be any way to do this. The first tap is always to focus, the second tap is to take the picture. You could simply tap the camera button and it will autofocus, if that is satisfactory.

Comment: Unfortunately not - seems like a massive oversight.