# Windows Phone Camera - Pin to Start?

Tags: camera

How do I pin the Windows Phone Camera to my Start Menu / Front Screen?

I have a Lumia 640 however I don't like the `Lumia Camera` App due to [a limitation](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/9915/1188) and so want a short-cut on the screen. I know you can access the Camera via the `Notification Centre` but I'd prefer an icon/tile.

I was used to having a dedicated camera button on the ATIV-S, but that's gone now unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

This following method is for any app which to want to pin on home screen.

1. Go to your home screen.
2. Swipe left to get app list.
3. Now press and hold on any app which you wanna pin. A pop up will appear.

There you will see options like Pin to start, rate and review, uninstall, share etc.

Select pin to start, and voila.

Comment: Sorry, there's no Windows Camera phone app in the list. (I assume you mean swipe-right).

Comment: Can you clarify which Camera app you are talking about.There is a CAMERA app.There is a Lumia Camera app or Nokia Camera app.

Comment: The default/built-in Windows Phone Camera app (not the Lumia/Nokia one). You can (only?) access it via Notification Centre if you've set your default camera app in settings.

Answer (score 1):

Your phone should have an app in the apps list simply called Camera. My Lumia 635 does, and I am able to hold it down until the menu appears, and it has a Pin to Start option.

Comment: Unfortunately not - there's no app called `Camera`. I can only find `Lumia Camera` in the Store (already installed).

Answer (score -1):

Why not change the default camera to "Camera" App if you do not like Lumia Camera?

For Windows Phone 8.1, follow these steps:

1. Goto Settings -> Swipe to Applications -> photos + camera
2. Change the Default camera app to "Microsoft Camera"

Comment: I have made this change - but I want to pin the Camera to the start menu.